# How to logout from facebook with LoginManager provided by react-native-fbsdk?

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

In simple, how does one log out with LoginManager provided by react-native-fbsdk?

If we look the code inside that LoginManager provided by react-native-fbsdk, we find this part regarding [logout](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/js/FBLoginManager.js):

```
  logOut() {
    LoginManager.logOut();
  },
```

**So no callback, or promise?** How do I really use this then? If I call *LoginManager.logout()*, it actually does perform the logout. But since I'm not allowed to pass any callback, and since it doesn't return a promise, then how do I know when the logout is done, or that was it successfull? I tried providing a callback, but it resulted in error. I also tried to return a promise from it, but it also returned an error. So I don't know how is this supposed to be used? It can't be synchronous logout, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think its not a synchronous function but also I think you don't need to wait for it to finish. You can just use it as synchronous. I'm thinking this because if you check the default [`LoginButton`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/js/FBLoginButton.js) on `react-native-fbsdk` [`onLogoutFinished`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/bd8b1fc3f0e97133c209bce42742dd937b8e1620/js/FBLoginButton.js#L63) prop doesn't pass any parameters about the logout action (successful, failed etc.). This means you can assume that its gonna happen without any problem since facebook itself assumed that. Default `LoginButton` [listens for events](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/bd8b1fc3f0e97133c209bce42742dd937b8e1620/js/FBLoginButton.js#L97) to run `onLogoutFinished` function. You can try to implement something like that if you really need to.

Comment: hi @bennygenel, Can i ask to you further info about this answer ? I want to trigger logout step from different page. I called `LoginManager.logOut()` but do nothing. How can i call logout function for react-native-fbsdk ?

Comment: @FatihAyyildiz if you didn't get any errors probably the function worked and you logged out from facebook but you need to handle logging out from your app too. Its hard to tell more without seeing a [mcve]. If you can't figure it out you can always create a new question with your specific case.

Comment: I made my repo to public. Could you check this repo to understand problem with facebook logout `https://github.com/fatihayyildiz/raffleapp`

Comment: @FatihAyyildiz I checked your code and can't find anything really. Maybe you should create a new question with a [mcve]. Someone else might help better than me.

Comment: import { LoginManager } from 'react-native-fbsdk';
...
 LoginManager.logOut();

works perfectly on me.

Comment: @ÇağdaşTunca after logging out can you sign up with another user? When I log out using `loginManager.logOut()` it does not let me enter the username and password for a different account. It keeps logging in with the same account

Comment: @HaseebBurki When you login with fbsdk app or web app opens and user enter his/hers crentials after you logout user with this way user logs out facebook within your app. Roughly speaking You can not call facebook apis with this user in your app anymore but user is still logged in facebook app or web app.  User still needs to logout from facebook app himself/herself.

Comment: Hi, what does loginManager.logOut() return upon success and failure? and does it need a try catch?

Comment: Did anyone figiure out how to solve this ?

Answer (score 3):

For me, this works:

```
import { LoginManager } from 'react-native-fbsdk'
LoginManager.logOut()
```

Answer (score 2):

**you can run something like this if you are using with firebase**

```
import { LoginManager } from 'react-native-fbsdk-next';

import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

const signOut = async () => {
    console.log('executing logout');

    try {
      LoginManager.logOut();
      const signOutResult = await auth().signOut();
      console.log('signOutResult', signOutResult);
      navigation.navigate('Root', { screen: 'Login' });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually after successfully login out the acsessToken becomes null.So after calling loginmanager.logout() you can check the accesstoken with AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() and if it comes null then you can safely assume that the logout has happened successfully.

```
LoginManager.logOut();
const token = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
if(_.isEmpty(token) {/* your code for doing logout related actions */}
```